# How to reduce distance between images in divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here are two images displayed in a div container:

[image]

The red line represents the distance between them and I've tried `padding` to reduce them but it isn't reducing anything.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1">


    <% for(var i=0; i<path.length; i++) { %>

            <div class="col-md-3" style=" display:inline-block;">
<img src='http://localhost:5000/public/Images/<%= path[i] %>' style="height: 200px; width: 200px; line-height: 0px"  alt="memes">  
</div>

  <% } %>
</div>  
</div>    
</div>
```

How do I reduce the distance using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html code like this.

Normal Bootstrap Approach:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offet-3">
        <img />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hacky bootstrap approach:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-center">
      <div class="row">
       <% for(var i=0; i<path.length; i++) { %>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <img />
        </div>
       <% } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add css class

```
.col-center {
display: table;
margin: 0 auto !important;
float: none !important; }
```

Comment: @AbiodunAdetona Adjust the col-md class to lower and add .img-responsive class to image

Comment: Okay. Good to hear now its working! Please upvote the answer to help others. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using bootstrap classes in this code. Here is a helpful link to the bootstrap grid system. 
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment

You should change your div classes, change the col-md-offset-1 to be col-md-4 and also change the col-md-3 to be col-md-4 and then wrap both of those divs with this div

`<div class="row justify-content-center">
</div>`

Comment: This closes all the distance. I still want some little spaces left.

Comment: Ok try changing the wrapping div to this class
<div class="row justify-content-around">
</div>
The distance between the pictures is going to adjust depending on the size of your screen because of the responsive way bootstrap works but it should be a good thing. Let me know if this class is better. You could also try leaving the current class in place but adding some padding to the images to get them to have some space between them,

Answer (score 0):

Padding cannot be negative, So adding a negative margin should work. Or else use position: relative and add left property. Add a code snippet of how it currently works. So people can understand better.